# How "official" is the Explorer's Guide to Wildemount book?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-adventurers-league, books

What's the state of *Explorer's Guide to Wildemount*? Was it playtested? Is it a valid resource for a Forgotten Realms campaign? Is it an AL-legal sourcebook - can I use it for the "+1" rule?

---

Related: [Is Matt Mercer's homebrew setting of Exandria now considered an official setting, as of the release of the "Explorer's Guide to Wildemount"?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/166529/)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The *Explorer's Guide to Wildemount* is official in that it is published by Wizards of the Coast, but none of its content is permitted in AL play. [This announcement](https://dndadventurersleague.org/dd-is-heading-to-wildemount/) on the D&D AL website says:

> As awesome as Critical Role is, we must say a Mighty Nein (that means “no” in Zemnian to those unfamiliar with the setting) to travelling to Wildemount in your Adventurers League campaigns. **There are no plans to allow Explorer[']s Guide to Wildemount or any of its offerings in the way of spells, classes, feats, etc. as a valid resource for Forgotten Realms or Oracle of War campaigns.**

Emphasis mine.

---

Everything below is in a sense obsolete, as [there is no more PHB+1 rule](https://yawningportal.dnd.wizards.com/blog/saying-goodbye-to-the-ph1-rule/), but the new structure for AL sources still does not permit *EGtW*.

---

Furthermore, the [AL Player's Guide](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/ALPGv92.pdf) explicitly lists what sources are permitted by the "PHB+1" rule in the Forgotten Realms AL campaign:

> Forgotten Realms characters can choose race and class options from the
> *Player’s Handbook* and one other resource—a rule called “PHB+1.”
> Additional resources include the following products:
>
> - *Elemental Evil Player’s Companion* (EEPC)
> - *Sword Coast Adventurer’s Guide* (SCAG)
> - *Volo’s Guide to Monsters* (VGM)
> - *Xanathar’s Guide to Everything* (XGE)<sup>1</sup>
> - *Mordenkainen’s Tome of Foes* (ToF)<sup>2</sup>
> - *Locathah Rising* (LR)
>
> Additionally, when selecting an additional source, the following
> variant or optional rules are available when you create your
> character:
>
> - Variant Human Traits (PHB)
> - Half-Elf and Tiefling Variants (SCAG/ToF)
> - Option: Human Languages (SCAG)<sup>3</sup>
> - Blessing of Corellon (ToF)<sup>3</sup>
>
> <sup>1</sup>XGE also includes the *“Tortle Package”*
> <sup>2</sup>Chapters 1 – 5, only
> <sup>3</sup>Taking this option can be done, even if its source
> product isn’t your selection for PHB+1

The AL [Oracle of War](https://dndadventurersleague.org/preparing-for-war-eberron-campaign-preview/) campaign (set in Eberron) has no “+1 Rule”; instead, it permits character options only from the PHB, *Eberron: Rising from the Last War*, and XGE. Character options from other sources, including the *Explorer's Guide to Wildemount* book, are not allowed.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, Eberron guides are also available for AL in Eberron campaigns.

Comment: Yeah I should hope so haha

Comment: @HellSaint, Forgotten Realms Player's Guide is separate from the Eberron Player's Guide. I don't have a copy of the Eberron PG in front of me to confirm but I believe only the FRPG has a +1 rule, whereas the EPG has a list of books that are usable; no +1.

Comment: @MivaScott I’ll do some research and confirm that, then add it to my answer if it matters.

Comment: Footnote #4 is slightly wrong; at the least, Xanathar's is allowed in the Oracle of War campaign as well now. You should consult the latest version of the documentation. I've edite the answer to correct this error now (and make it clear that the footnotes are actually from the ALPG as well, save for the last one which doesn't actually need to be a footnote.